# Proving that there exists a set $F\subset S(A)$, such that $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(F)$ and $\color{blue} \mu^*(F\setminus E)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Notations**: $X$ is a given set.  $A$ is an algebra given on $X$. $S(A):=$ the sigma algebra generated by $A$. $\mu: A\to [0,\infty]$ is a $\sigma-$ finite measure (some people call it pre-measure). For brevity, often times $\mu^*S:=\mu^*(S)$ or $\mu S=\mu^* S$.

The following theorem is to be proven:

Suppose that $E\subset X$, then there exists a set $F\subset S(A)$, the sigma algebra generated by algebra such that $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(F)$ and $\color{blue} \mu^*(F\setminus E)=0$.

I don't understand some portions of its proof. The outline of the proof is as under along with some comments:

1. $E=\cup_n E_n$, a disjoint union such that $\mu^* E_j<\infty$ for all $n$.

**Proof:** Since $\mu$ is sigma finite, there exist disjoint $\{S_i\}_i\subset A, X=\cup_iS_i,\mu S_i\lt \infty.$ So $E=E\cap X$.

2. Finding sets $F_j\in S(A), E_j\subset F_j$ and $\mu^* E_j=\mu^* F_j$ for every $j$.

Comment: Fix $j$ and fix any $n$. There exist $\{E_{n, k}\}_k\subset A, E_j\subset \cup_k E_{n,k}$ and $\sum_k\mu(E_{n,k})\le \mu^* E+\frac 1n$. Take $F_j=\cap_n (\cup_k E_{n,k}). $

3. Take any $G\in S(A)$ such that $G\subset F_j- E_j$ (this can be done as empty set is in the sigma algebra) and show that $\mu^*G=0$.

**Proof**: $E_j\subset F_j- G$. It follows that $\mu^* E_j\le mu^* F_j-\mu^*G\le \mu^* F_j\implies \mu^*G=0$, using $(2)$.

4. It follows from $(3)$ that $\mu^*(F_j- E_j)=0$.

I need help in understanding why $(4)$ follows from $(3)$. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I think something is missing here (or I am missing something). If $\mu^* (F \setminus E) = 0$ then since $F \setminus E$ has outer measure zero, it is measurable and so $F \setminus ( F \setminus E ) = E$ is measurable.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks a lot for the comment. I think the second half of the theorem is not correct. Because as you said, that would imply E is measurable, which need not be the case.